# Return correct http error status code to browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my global.asax I have written code into the Application_Error event which catches all errors and shows a generic error page to the user as well as logging/emailing the error that occurred.

However, I have realised that the error page does not return the correct status code to the browser which has meant that, to a service like UptimeRobot, the site is still seen as functioning even when the page is broken.

Is it possible to derive the correct status code from an error and return it to the browser?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Response.StatusCode` property on the page?

Comment: @DGibbs That wouldn't work because IIS intercepts error codes and redirects to a debug or error page (unless you explicitly set TrySkipIisCustomErrors to true, see answer below).

Comment: @DennisTraub It will work if `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors(v=vs.110).aspx has been used.

Comment: @DGibbs That's what I already posted in my answer below. I edited my previous comment to clarify.

Comment: @DennisTraub I am aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

By default IIS intercepts the status code and sends either the debug info or a custom error page. You can deactivate this default behavior and manually set the error code through the Response object:

```
Context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;  
Context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
Context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Context.Response.Write("Your error message");
```